# Display ID within QR Code

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, qr-code

I'm trying to get the current `survey id` to show within my QR code, however it's only displaying

```
$survey->id
```

I'm sure there is something simple I'm missing (first laravel project). Any help would be appreciated.

Reference [simple software QR](https://www.simplesoftware.io/docs/simple-qrcode)

View

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->size(200)->generate('localhost:8000/survey/view/$survey->id')) !!} ">
```

Comment: try `->generate('localhost:8000/survey/view/'.$survey->id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are echoing `$survey->id` as a string, you want to use the value of said variable.

To do this you will need to remove it from the string and instead place it as the variable inside your url.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->size(200)->generate('localhost:8000/survey/view/'.$survey->id)) !!} ">
```

Furthermore you might want to change the way your generate your link and instead use route names or the actions instead of the hardcoded local host, this might give trouble when deploying your application.